# print(i, end = ",") wont print the last i

Tags: python, counting

I would like to take a number and print all even numbers up to and including the number, here's my current code,

```
def print_upto(number):
    for i in range(0, int(number)):
        if(i % 2 == 0):
            print(i, end = ',')
```

my issue is that when I put print_upto(50) it prints from 0 all the way to 48, not 50. I am not sure how to get it to print 50, I have tried adding

```
elif(i == number) and (number % 2 == 0):
        print(number)
```

however, this doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `range`'s stop argument is exclusive.

Comment: The upperbound of a range is *exclusive*.

Comment: You should have printed all the numbers in your `for` loop, and ask yourself why you wouldn't see a `50` appear in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change to:

```
for i in range(0, int(number + 1))
```

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-range) generates numbers *up to*, but *not including* the given number.